# C# find cost, calculate the cost of item and include 10% GST

Tags: c#-2.0

I am studying C# and have been asked to create a grocery program.  I am stuck and can't seem to find anything on the net to help me.  I have created a grocery item class with properties containing Name and Price. I have also created a subclass of purchasedItem which has an integer of quantity.  I now need to create a method which finds Price, calculates the Price and adds 10% GST.  Any ideas of how to do this.
This is what I have so far - any help would be appreciated:

```
namespace Groceries1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            groceryItem mygroceryItem = new groceryItem();
            mygroceryItem.play();
            purchasedItem mypurchasedItem = new purchasedItem();
        }
        class groceryItem
        {
            private string myName = 0;
            private int myPrice = 0;

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                     return myName;
                }
                set
                {
                    myName = value;
                }
            }
            public int Price
            {
                get
                {
                    return myPrice;
                }
                set
                {
                    myPrice = value;
                }
            }
        }
        class purchasedItem
        {
            private int myquantity = 0;

                public int quantity
                {
                get
                {
                    return myquantity;
                }
                set
                {
                    myquantity = Price*quantity*1.1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Groceries
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FreshGrocery freshGrocery = new FreshGrocery();
            freshGrocery.Name = "Fresh grocery";
            freshGrocery.Price = 30;
            freshGrocery.Weight = 0.5;

            Grocery grocery = new Grocery();
            grocery.Name = "Grocery";
            grocery.Price = 50;
            grocery.Quantity = 2;

            ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.Orders = new List<GroceryItem>();
            cart.Orders.Add(freshGrocery);
            cart.Orders.Add(grocery);

            double price = cart.Calculate();
            Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", price);
        }
   }

   abstract class GroceryItem
   {
       private string name;
       private double price = 0;

       public string Name
       {
           get
           {
               return name;
           }
           set
           {
               name = value;
           }
       }

       public double Price
       {
           get
           {
               return price;
           }
           set
           {
               price = value;
           }
       }

       public abstract double Calculate();
   }    

   class FreshGrocery: GroceryItem
   {
       private double weight = 0;

       public double Weight
       {
           get
           {
               return weight;
           }
           set
           {
               weight = value;
           }
       }

       public override double Calculate() {
          return this.Price * this.Weight;
       }
   }    

   class Grocery: GroceryItem
   {
       private int quantity = 0;
       private double gst = 10; // In Percentage

       public int Quantity
       {
           get
           {
               return quantity;
           }
           set
           {
               quantity = value;
           }
       }

       public override double Calculate() {
          double calculatedPrice = this.Price * this.Quantity;

          // VAT
           if(calculatedPrice > 0)
           {
               calculatedPrice += calculatedPrice * (gst/100);
           }

          return calculatedPrice;
       }
   }

    class ShoppingCart
    {
        private List<GroceryItem> orders;

        public List<GroceryItem> Orders
        {
            get
            {
                return orders;
            }
            set
            {
                orders = value;
            }
        }

        public double Calculate()
        {
            double price = 0;
            if(this.Orders != null)
            {

                foreach(GroceryItem order in this.Orders)
                {
                    price += order.Calculate();
                }

            }
            return price;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aruna, thanks for the suggested code.  I tried it and i am getting an errors with the code

Comment: Can you tell me what's the error and I can fix it. I just coded directly here and didn't execute it.

Comment: 1. cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?). 2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. 3.'Program.ShoppingCart.Calculate()':not all code paths return a value 4. 'List<Program.PurchasedItem> does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and not extension method 'Calculate' accepting first argument of type 'List<Program.PurchasedItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  Would love to hear your thoughts on these errors.  Cheers

Comment: I have updated the code and please check. Still, I didn't execute the code but please let me know in case of any errors. I will try to execute it once I am back to home.

Comment: @McKimmie79 Okay, I have updated the working code and can execute it successfully. Please give a try now and should be good :-)

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly.  One last question - How would i add a subclass to PurchasedItem for freshItems which has a property of weight, a double type which also finds the cost method and uses a formula of weight * price and does not include GST?

Comment: @McKimmie79 Updated the code. Please have a look for fresh grocery with weight and not including GST.

Comment: I have a file called groceries and this file contain the following information:
regular,cereal,4.00,1      
fresh,rump steak,11.99,0.8 
which equals type of item, item, cost, quantity if a regular item - weight if fresh item.
If the item is regular then 10% GST applies if the item is fresh in no GST applies.
how do i write the following to the invoice file
"Groceries for you" as the title, todays date, list each item in the groceries file, count the number of items, work out the GST on the regular items and then list the total $ amount at the bottom of the file..  Any ideas? code edited